# GPUImage for face blending

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, face-detection, gpuimage

I have a face blending application where I need to mix the face features(say the polygonal shape formed by enclosing the 2 eyes and mouth position of one face with other). i .e I would need to extract a polygon of one face and blend it (or kind of replace it) with the new face.

Ive done the polygonal extraction and it went quite well, but Im having issues in the blending side. I've turned to GPUImage because Ive heard it to be really good.

Im trying to use GPUImagePoissonBlendFilter but then blending is not working properly.

Do you guys have any experience using GPUImagePoissonBlendFilter before?. i.e Is there any filters to be used in combination with GPUImagePoissonBlendFilter?

Or can you suggest any other blending filters within the GPUImage library which is suitable for this type of blending?

Comment: Hi i have tried working on such app but the blending is not always smooth i dont see any app doing it smoothly either. It will be difficult to make fully automated blending app. The result required is a mixture of filture

Comment: can you be more specific?i.e mixture of filter ?

Comment: its a combination of blurr smudge also involves eye and face detection etc. and the ammount of each filter will vary based on images being merged

Comment: can you give me the code for blending ?detection not needed.

Comment: I'm pointing this to the newer, more detailed question apparently asked by one of your coworkers.